# How to initialize NSString as text with double quotes

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i want to initialize NSString is as "hai" with double qoutes..is it possible? any help please?
but NSString *str = @"hai"; i want to convert it as "hai" without direct initialization?any help pls?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to convert an existing string please use this:

```
NSString *newString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",str];
```

Answer (score 2):

`NSString* foo = @"\"hai\"";`

Comment: but NSString *str = @"hai";
i want to convert it as "hai" without direct initialization?any help pls?

Comment: psychotik gave you the correct answer.
what do you mean without direct initialization???

you have to use \" where ever you want " to be a part of your string, even when theres no direct initialization (whatever you mean by that)..