# Add double quote to NSString attach to the variable

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, nsdictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to initialize NSString as text with double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3115924/how-to-initialize-nsstring-as-text-with-double-quotes)

How can I add tan actual double quote to a variable inside on NSString to be used in NSDictionary?
Example

```
NSString *ename=@"John Doe";
NSDictionary *profile=@{@"Profile":@{"Name":ename}};
```

I need to display like this "Profile":{"Name":"John Doe"}

Comment: you need to display name or need to save in dictionary ?

Comment: save in nsdictionary first then display

Comment: @vikingosegundo: Please dont close this is not a duplicate.

Comment: @baste: It looks as if your are trying to create JSON output. In that case you can use `NSJSONSerialization`, instead of stuffing quotation marks into the strings (see answer below).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I need to display like this "Profile":{"Name":"John Doe"}

Do you want to create JSON format? Then you can use the built-in class `NSJSONSerialization`:

```
NSString *ename = @"John Doe";
NSDictionary *profile = @{@"Profile":@{@"Name":ename}};

NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:profile options:0 error:NULL];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSLog(@"%@", jsonString);
```

*Output:*

```
{"Profile":{"Name":"John Doe"}}
```

Comment: yes, i did this, :) thank you

Answer (score 5):

Use escape charater **\** ...

```
NSString *ename=@"This is double \" quote \"";
```

If you are asking for adding quotes in **Key** of dictionary, then you have to add some special character, (non-alphabet and non-numerical) only then key shows double quotes.

`[... description] simply wraps things in quotes for display that have non-alphanumeric characters in them.`

**And there is no difference between "abc" and abc in debugger. This is used only for dubugging and the actual value is always a NSString @"abc".**

Comment: how to do this inside nsdictionary

Comment: As i mentioned in my answer, you **CAN NOT** you need to use some special character like space or something else, but that will also come with " & ".

Comment: If there is some hack then I am waiting for the solution.

Comment: I tried this one, but also failed :  NSString *quotedProfile=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\"%@\"",@"Profile"];
    
   NSString *ename=@"John Doe";
    NSDictionary *profile=@{@"Profile":@{@"Name":ename}};
   // I need to display like this "Profile":{"Name":"John Doe"}
    NSLog(@"-> %@",profile);

Comment: thank you for your time AKV definitely there is a solution for here, i have a variable that needs to be in dictionary and send as json

Comment: Check my update... What solution you got? that one in my comment?

Comment: just an idea but not yet tested, i will use like this NSString *X =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ename];

Comment: and remember as you are using one special character(") for key, the description method will add extra quotes for you, so you will end up with more quotes than you actually required.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
NSString *string=@"This is test \" for \"";
```

Hope it helps you..

Comment: hi prateek what is the word "for" is another variable

Comment: @baste Is simple text fr you to understand

Comment: sorry i mean what if the word for is another variable with data inside like NSString *for =@"again";

Comment: @baste no variable just use / before "

Comment: If you are using NSDictionary, then fetch data in NSString and then use \..